# Github Actions is unable to create resources in AWS mentioned in a Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

terraform plan shows correct result when run locally but does not create resource mentioned in module when run on GitHub actions. The other resources in root main.tf (s3) are created fine.

Root project:-

```
    terraform {
      backend "s3" {
        bucket = "sd-tfstorage"
        key    = "terraform/backend"
        region = "us-east-1"
      }
    }
    locals {
      env_name         = "sandbox"
      aws_region       = "us-east-1"
      k8s_cluster_name = "ms-cluster"
    }
    # Network Configuration

    module "aws-network" {
      source                = "github.com/<name>/module-aws-network"
      env_name              = local.env_name
      vpc_name              = "msur-VPC"
      cluster_name          = local.k8s_cluster_name
      aws_region            = local.aws_region
      main_vpc_cidr         = "10.10.0.0/16"
      public_subnet_a_cidr  = "10.10.0.0/18"
      public_subnet_b_cidr  = "10.10.64.0/18"
      private_subnet_a_cidr = "10.10.128.0/18"
      private_subnet_b_cidr = "10.10.192.0/18"
    }

    # EKS Configuration
    # GitOps Configuration
```

module:-

```
    provider "aws" {
      region = var.aws_region
    }

    locals {
      vpc_name     = "${var.env_name} ${var.vpc_name}"
      cluster_name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.env_name}"
    }

    ## AWS VPC definition
    resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
      cidr_block           = var.main_vpc_cidr
      enable_dns_support   = true
      enable_dns_hostnames = true

      tags = {
        "Name"                                        = local.vpc_name,
        "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared",
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

When you run it locally, you are using the default aws profile to plan it.

Have you set up your github environment with the correct aws access to perform those actions?